# Help with understanding this Theorem: $G/G^0\cong G_x/G_x\cap G^0$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

I have difficulties prove and understanding the second statement of this theorem. I tried to construct the homomorphism
$$\varphi:G_x\to G/G^0$$
given by $\varphi(g)=gG^0$ where $G^0$ is a connected component of the identity $e$ in $G$ i.e. $G^0$ is normal in $G$. I can show that $ker(\varphi)=G_x\cap G_0$. But, how do I show that $\varphi$ is surjective?

[image]

Comment: You are trying to prove that $G_xG^0=G$, which is equivalent to $G^0$ acting transitively on $X$, which is the topic of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140394)

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you!